# Dropdown menu in android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I wanna make a dropdown-menu like the one in the attached picture  in android I searched a lot but I Couldn't find anything?

Could you tell me how to start?

[image: dropdown-menu]

Comment: Please consider adding a screenshot to your post explaining what you think a "dropdown-menu" is in Android. For example, you might post a screenshot of a "dropdown-menu" that you have seen in another application. You can use DDMS (standalone or the Eclipse plugin) to take the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not generally use a "dropdown-menu" like the one you have in your screenshot. I encourage you to learn the Android UI framework and stick to it.

In Honeycomb (the tablet UI), there is the "nav mode" of the action bar that will look a bit similar, though it is not designed to be a menu.

Comment: Actually I meant the menu I showed up there not a spinner.But I appreciate your help guys.

@CommonsWare Do you suggest that I use spinner or do you know something else closer to my objective?

Comment: @FAFI: As I indicated in my answer, your objective is wrong. Android applications do not use "dropdown-menus". I am not aware of any current mobile OS that does. Please follow standard UI conventions for the platform. Since I have absolutely no idea what the business problem is that you are trying to solve, I cannot tell you if a `Spinner` or an options menu or something else is the right answer.

Comment: Actually it's more than just the list nav mode of the action bar, `Spinner` widgets as of Honeycomb use the in-place dropdown style by default. `android.widget.PopupMenu` also offers a simple API for presenting these style menus anchored to arbitrary views.

Comment: @adamp: Your solutions are for Honeycomb. The community has no idea how it will play out on Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) as Google tries to put part of Honeycomb into a phone-sized screen -- for all we know, on phones nav mode in the action bar won't be supported and `PopupMenu` will be frowned upon. Combine that with the need to support the 99.4% of Android devices in use today that run pre-Honeycomb versions of Android, and I am not comfortable advising people to employ a "dropdown-menu" UI at this time. If UX folk at Google have recommendations for us in this area, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: @adamp: I was in the room for that presentation. I do not recall Reto covering the topic under debate in this question. It's a good presentation, though.

Comment: Reto wasn't on stage for that one. :) I wanted to highlight Matias's answer during Q&A that the stylings shown in Honeycomb represent the direction we're exploring going forward. Popups are fine when used appropriately. They're also not without precedent in Android pre-3.0. See quick contact badges, context menus in the new Google Music app, and the stock Camera and Gallery apps for examples. Implementation details vary, but `android.widget.PopupWindow` isn't a bad place to start. It's not quite as turnkey as `PopupMenu` but it will get the job done.

Comment: @adamp: Oops, sorry, I read the title and was thinking Reto's one. I was in this presentation as well. My apologies.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to do something where you see a list of items as you type in text into a TextView, you may be looking for an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html). An implementation example can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).

If you are trying for the more usual drop down menu, you may want to use a [Spinner widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html). An example of its implementation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html).

Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be to make a view with the menu you want. 
Then make an animation that will grow the X and Y scale over some amount of time.

Ex:

```
android:fromXScale="0.1"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:fromYScale="0.1"
android:toYScale="1.0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="0%"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
```

Then all you have to do is apply the application to your view in the appropriate onclicklistener